# SVN on https easy setup

Tags: ubuntu, svn

What's the best way to setup SVN on https on a fresh ubuntu installation?

Comment: sounds more like a superuser question to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get [HTTPS working.](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/httpd.html#https-configuration) You can generate a self signed certificate, or go the extra twenty dollars and get a valid certificate for the domain. Probably, you want to keep the private key unencrypted because the alternative require the typing of a password by a person.

Then use the [SVN module that works via webDAV](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s04.html). Set up an apache config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and use a2ensite to make it live.

Comment: How do I get https working?  I'm totally new to this, it's my first time setting up a server. I have SVN installed and am not able to access the SVN via the local IP on our network attempted through an SSH connection. (yes I have ssh installed)

Comment: I'll add a bit on HTTPS